# Having separate captions for algorithms inside a tabular

Tags: tables, captions, algorithms, ieeetran

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,conference,compsocconf,letterpaper]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm*}%[H]
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
        \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
            \begin{algorithmic}[1]
                \State $c_x = c_x + 1$
            \end{algorithmic}
            \caption{Alg A}
            \label{alg:a}                           
        \end{minipage}
        &
        \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}    
            \begin{algorithmic}[1]
                \State $c_x = c_m + 1$  
            \end{algorithmic}
            \caption{Alg B}
            \label{alg:b}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{tabular}
\end{algorithm*}\end{document}
```

Which produces:
[image]

Notice that it does not show the caption of Alg A, as it is being run over by the caption of B.

> **How do I make the caption of each algorithm display above the algorithm?**

---

I've tried using the `%\usepackage{subcaption}` package, but it conflicts with other packages I'm using, not sure which (possibly `subfig`).

Comment: `\captionof{algorithm}{Your caption}` perhaps?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - where would you place it? I've tried using `captionof` on several locations, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Which package provides `algorithm` ???

Comment: Why are you posting such fragments? Shall we look into every `algorithm` - package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set an `algorithm` using the `[H]` float specifier, it is actually set inside a `minipage`. That means you can technically place the algorithm inside *another* float (like `figure`, to obtain the floating behaviour that is typical of `algorithm`), yet still get captions and references to `algorithm`s:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algpseudocode,algorithm}
\usepackage{lipsum}% Just for this example

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

See Algorithm~\ref{alg:a} and~\ref{alg:b} for more detail.

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.475\textwidth}
    \vspace*{-\baselineskip}% Vertical correction
    \begin{algorithm}[H]
      \caption{Alg A}\label{alg:a}
      \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \State $c_x = c_x + 1$
        \State $d_y = d_y - 1$
      \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
  \end{minipage}%
  \hfill\vrule\hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.475\textwidth}
    \vspace*{-\baselineskip}% Vertical correction
    \begin{algorithm}[H]
      \caption{Alg B}\label{alg:b}
      \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \State $c_x = c_m + 1$
      \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

To limit the width of the non-floating `algorithm`, we place it inside a `minipage` of fixed width. A `[t]`op-alignment ensures that algorithms of different sizes (vertically) are aligned properly (without this specification, the default alignment is vertically centred).

`\vrule` sets the two algorithms apart in the same way it would have if placed inside a `tabular` with a vertical column rule.

---

If used under the [`IEEEtran` document class](http://ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran) you can place the algorithms in their same format as above inside a

```
\begin{figure*}[!t]
  <algorithms here>
\end{figure*}
```

double-column figure. Note that the figure will only appear on the page *following* its declaration, as is customary with two-column documents.

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference,letterpaper]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{algpseudocode,algorithm}
\usepackage{lipsum}% Just for this example

\begin{document}

% Algorithms are declared on page 1, but will only show at top of page 2.
\begin{figure*}[!t]
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.475\textwidth}
    \vspace*{-\baselineskip}% Vertical correction
    \begin{algorithm}[H]
      \caption{Alg A}\label{alg:a}
      \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \State $c_x = c_x + 1$
        \State $d_y = d_y - 1$
      \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
  \end{minipage}%
  \hfill\vrule\hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.475\textwidth}
    \vspace*{-\baselineskip}% Vertical correction
    \begin{algorithm}[H]
      \caption{Alg B}\label{alg:b}
      \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \State $c_x = c_m + 1$
      \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure*}

See Algorithm~\ref{alg:a} and~\ref{alg:b} for more detail.
\lipsum[1-17]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks so much Werner! Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me. I've used the `article` document class because I wasn't sure if it makes sense to use different ones, but I'm writing a two-columns paper (`\documentclass[10pt,conference,compsocconf,letterpaper]{IEEEtran}`), and your solution makes the algorithms appear one below the other :/ .

Comment: @RB: *Always* include a *MWE* that *replicates* your problem. Don't say you're using `article` when you're actually using something as specific as a journal document class.

Comment: I've edited the post. Truly sorry about this, still learning how to use this site :/ .

Comment: @RB: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm*}%[H]
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Algorithm}\\
\hline
Alg A & Alg B\\
\hline
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
   \State $c_x = c_x + 1$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{minipage}
&
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State $c_x = c_m + 1$  
\end{algorithmic}
\end{minipage}
\end{tabular}
\end{algorithm*}
\end{document}
```

output
  [image: algo]

Comment: Thanks, but this does not allow me to refer to these algorithms from outside (it has no labels associated with them). i.e., I can't then do "in Algorithm~\ref{alg:a} we get that...".